# Tactic for comparing dataframes when column names are different and sequence is unknown

Tags: python, pandas

I need to compare two DataFrames at at time to find out if the values match or not.  One DataFrame is from an Excel workbook and the other is from a SQL query.  The problem is that not only might the columns be out of sequence, but the column headers might have a different name as well.  This would prevent me from simply getting the Excel column headers and using those to rearrange the columns in the SQL DataFrame.  In addition, I will be doing this across several tabs in an excel work book and against different queries.  Not only do the column names differ from excel to SQL, but they may also differ from excel to excel and SQL to SQL.

I did create a solution, but not only is it very choppy, but I'm concerned it will begin to take up a considerable amount of memory to run.

The solution entails using lists in a list.  If the excel value is in the same list as the SQL value they are considered a match and the function will return the final order that the SQL DataFrame must change to in order to match the same order that the Excel DataFrame is using.  In case I missed some possibilities and the newly created order list has a different length than what is needed, I simply return the original SQL list of headers in the original order.

The example below is barely a fraction of what I will actually be working with.  The actual number of variations and column names are much higher than the example below. Any suggestions anyone has on how to improve this function, or offer a better solution to this problem,  would be appreciated.

**Here is an example:**

```
#Example data
exceltab1 = {'ColA':[1,2,3],
        'ColB':[3,4,1],
        'ColC':[4,1,2]}

exceltab2 = {'cColumn':[10,15,17],
         'aColumn':[5,7,8],
        'bColumn':[9,8,7]}

sqltab1 = {'Col/A':[1,2,3],
        'Col/C':[4,1,2],
        'Col/B':[3,4,1]}

sqltab2 = {'col_banana':[9,8,7],
         'col_apple':[5,7,8],
        'col_carrot':[10,15,17]}

#Code
import pandas as pd
ec1 = pd.DataFrame(exceltab1)
ec2 = pd.DataFrame(exceltab2)

sq1 = pd.DataFrame(sqltab1)
sq2 = pd.DataFrame(sqltab2)


#This will fail because the columns are out of order
result1 = (ec1.values == sq1.values).all()


def translate(excel_headers ,sql_headers):
    translator = [["ColA", "aColumn", "Col/A", "col_apple"],
    ["ColB", "bColumn", "Col/B", "col_banana"],
    ["ColC", "cColumn", "Col/C", "col_carrot"]]
    order = []
for i in range(len(excel_headers)):
        for list in translator:
            for item in sql_headers:
                if excel_headers[i] in list and item in list:
                    order.append(item)
                    break
    if len(order) != len(sql_headers):
        return sql_headers
    else:
        return order


sq1 =sq1[translate(list(ec1.columns), list(sq1.columns))]


#This will pass because the columns now line up
result2 = (ec1.values == sq1.values).all()

print(f"Result 1: {result1} , Result 2: {result2}")
```

**Result:**
Result 1: False , Result 2: True

Answer (score 0):

No code, but an algorithm.

We have a set of columns A and another B. We can compare a column from A and another from B and see if they're equal. We do that for all combinations of columns.

This can be seen as a bipartite graph where there are two groups of vertices A and B (one vertex for each column), and an edge exists between two vertices if those two columns are equal. Then the problem of translating column names is equivalent to finding a perfect matching in this bipartite graph.

An algorithm to do this with is Hopkroft-Karp, which has a Python implementation [here](https://pypi.org/project/hopcroftkarp/). That finds maximum matchings, so you still have to check whether it found a perfect matching (that is, each column from A has an associated column from B).